# How to specify a function type in the parameters of a Kotlin lambda?

Tags: kotlin

So I was trying to register some functions in a map, the code can be resumed like this:

```kotlin
private val things = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

fun put(name: String, value: Any) {
    things[name] = value
}

fun main() {
    put("foo") { a: String, b: (() -> String) ->
        println(a + b())
    }
}
```

[(Code on Kotlin Playground)](https://pl.kotl.in/T8zec47Mf)

But the kotlin parser complains about the type of `c` and I get for line 8 and 9:

```
Unresolved reference: a
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
Unresolved reference: a
Unresolved reference: b
```

It seems like a bug but I'm not sure.

Of course, this could be worked around my specifying the type of `value` in `register` to `(String, () -> String) -> Unit`, but this is the API and I have no access to it.

This could also be worked around by using a `Function0<String>`, but why wouldn't it work with the more "kotlin" syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the parentheses around the function type worked for me:

```
put("foo") { a: String, b: () -> String ->
    println(a + b())
}
```

I do agree this is weird. You can put parentheses around `String`, but not `() -> String`. This also works with anonymous function literals:

```
put("foo", fun(a: String, b: (() -> String)) {
    
})
```

The [syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html#grammar-rule-type) in the language spec does say that `type` can be a `parenthesizedType`:

```
type:
[typeModifiers] (functionType | parenthesizedType | nullableType | typeReference | definitelyNonNullableType)
```

Perhaps there is some quirk in the parser that causes the parsing the fail...

Comment: interestingly, it works if you put a comma at the end: `{ a: (String), b: (() -> String), ->`

Comment: the issue presents itself also with this simple case: `a: (String) ->`. I assume it's because the compiler expects `a` to be a function instead of a parenthesized type